# How to save agora stream in Android?

Tags: android, agora.io

I am using agora sdk for streaming. I want to save the stream in agora cloud. How I can save the stream in agora cloud?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Agora Cloud Recording service to achieve this. You can refer to the Cloud Recording quick start guide to understand how to implement the Cloud Recording feature: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest?platform=RESTful